# Can Ethereum be successful in a world where EOS meets all of its promises? Why/Why Not?

Tags: contract-deployment, dapps, economics

As the title states, the EOS platform looks incredibly promising, but looking at the recent blog posts the maximum 6k transactions per second is much less than the promised 100k+ per second. I'm aware that this is because multi-threading isn't implemented yet, but EOS has made many exciting promises that are yet to come to fruition.

So my question is, do you believe Ethereum still has a place in the blockchain industry if EOS can follow through on all promises? What will Ethereum's niche be or do you believe it will still be a dominant technology?

Comment: Hi there. This sort of question is likely to lead to subjective/opinionated answers. "Successful" is relative, and you're likely to get answers which lead to drawn-out discussions, which aren't a good fit for this site. Reddit would be a better place to ask: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I've tried to have a discussion similar to this on reddit before and I found the discussion to be non-quantitative and not from developers themselves. That is why I chose to ask in this community.

Comment: This is a good question with potentially interesting answers. I hope it will not be closed by the community here.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm glad you agree with me, I encourage you to vote up the question to show the moderators that the community is interested.

Comment: Good thing we're not on stack overflow.